# I want to learn WordPress without purchasing domain and hosting

Tags: wordpress

I want to learn WordPress but setting up a hosting domain and all the initial process is frustrating for me and I don’t want to get into this.

Is there anything which can help me to create a quick WordPress site without purchasing a domain or hosting so that I can start learning and start creating websites with WordPress, when I will learn everything I will be in a position to purchase hosting/domain.

Anyone know of any of these kinds of services?

I am trying to find a solution or any tool for my problem.

Comment: You can install WordPress on your local machine. It's the cheapest way to play around with it. Once you're confident enough you can then find a hosted service to deploy your WordPress installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many services you can use to play around with WordPress.

1. InstaWP - they have a 3 sites limit at a time, you can spin up a site for 7 days. They offer an internal migration tool which can be used to migrate to any hosting service.
2. TasteWP - i think they have a 48 hours limit on temp sites.
3. LocalWP - it is a local development environment, you will need to download and install a 350 mb file to get started. You can keep the site forever, but you can't share the sites easily.

Comment: Hi Vikas 

Thanks for answering my query. I will definitely try out these tools.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in these modern times would be to use Docker to set up a local or test site to get started with. Docker is available on multiple platforms and there are lots of articles on the web dealing with quickly setting up Wordpress locally with it.

If you need external access (you already own a domain) then you will need a server of some sort (unless you have a static IP for your local isp) then something like this would do it:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-compose